# visitor ip changes within 10 seconds

Tags: php, .net, ip, video-streaming

When a visitor enters my website, I keep track of their IP address. When they open a video on the website, I send this IP address as part of an encoded URL request to a server that streams the video. To be able to stream the video the IP address in the decoded URL parameter should be the same as the URL requesting the stream.

Now I noticed that is not always the same. I understand clearly, that if there would be a lot of time between entering the website and streaming video, the IP can have changed due to NAT, gateways, etc. But actually it is happening within a time-frame of several seconds. See log file below.

The difference in code between the website and the streaming server is:

1. Website is written in .NET   -> **detect IP using:** Request.UserHostAddress
2. Streaming server uses PHP to stream the video. --> **detect ip using:** `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

What I want to achieve,that the video stream urls on the website, that surely will be collected by spiders, remote websites etc., can not be used for downloading or playing the video remotely. I am aware of temp URL solution but I only want to implement it if there is no easy way to tackle my current issue.

My questions:

1. Why does this happen? Am is using the wrong code to detect the IP address?
2. Any better solution how to tackle this?

> User: 125.38.245.164 - July 8, 2015, 8:22 pm
>
> Attempt: using different IP to access: 03bc9af8-18bd-4cf6-9de1-dea70a663306
>
> IP in request:123.151.42.57
>
> IP detected:125.38.245.164
>
> User: 114.4.21.210 - July 8, 2015, 8:23 pm
>
> Attempt: using different IP to access: 68fa4850-2db7-49e1-b26e-bf37f807ed9c
>
> IP in request:107.167.103.80
>
> IP detected:114.4.21.210
>
> User: 111.206.36.14 - July 8, 2015, 8:23 pm
>
> Attempt: using different IP to access: af874ac0-ca54-4537-bb0d-4daed5dd98af
>
> IP in request:222.188.143.242
>
> IP detected:111.206.36.14

Answer (score 0):

If user is behind a proxy you may want to look for the forwarded header:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] 
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']
```

If any of these is set, this means that request is coming from some kind of proxy service.